# Apache htaccess reverse proxy ends up in a 301 loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, reverse, reverse-proxy

I only have access to `.htaccess`, within which I'm adding a reverse proxy from a domain to a subdomain of that domain.

Currently, my line is:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ http://blog.site.co.uk/$1 [P,L]
```

The url `www.site.co.uk/blog` successfully gets the content from the subdomain, but with a trailing slash and any page after the request ends up in a 301 loop.

How can I stop this from happening?

I also use `RewriteBase /`, not sure if this is a trailing slash issue...